# Problem with ParametricPlot with Im and Re

Tags: plotting, syntax

I have a problem, How can I plot theses functions from 0 to 2 Pi :

Re(e^(iaϕ+(iϕ)^b)), Im(e^(icϕ+(iϕ)^d))

Re(e^((iϕ)^a) e^((iϕ)^b )), Im(e^(icϕ+(iϕ)^d))

Re(e^(iaϕ+(iϕ)^b)), Im(e^((iϕ)^c) e^((iϕ)^d))

Re(e^((iϕ)^a+(iϕ)^b)), Im(e^((iϕ)^c+(iϕ)^d))

with a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0 and then a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 1 ...
a = 10, b = 10, c = 10, d = 10

I'm really new to Mathematica, I tried this for one function:

```
ParametricPlot[{Re[e^((i phi)^a + (i phi)^b)], Im[e^(((i phi)^c + (i phi)^d))]}, {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

with a = 1, b = 1, c = 1 and d = 1, but all I get is a blank plot.

I also tried :

```
P[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  ParametricPlot[
  {
    e^(i a t)*e^(i b t),
    e^(i c t)*e^(i d t)
  }, 
  {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Axes -> False];

P[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Again, a blank plot.

Comment: Use `E` (note the capitalization) for the exponential constant; `e` has no built-in meaning. Alternatively, use `Exp[]`.

Comment: ... and `i` should be `I`, since *Mathematica* uses capital `I` for the imaginary unit. And make sure your variable matches your plotting variable: in the first example `phi` and `[Phi]` had better match.

Comment: P[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  ParametricPlot[{Re (E^(I *a* t)*E^(I *b* t)), 
    Im (E^(I* c* t)*E^(I* d* t))}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False];
P[1, 1, 1, 1] , it's still blank, thank you for your answers.

Comment: P[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  ParametricPlot[{Re (Exp[(I *a* t)]*Exp[(I *b* t)]), 
    Im (Exp[(I *c* t)]*Exp[(I *d* t)])}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False];
P[1, 1, 1, 1] blank too,

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you get started:

```
func[a_, b_, ϕ_] := Exp[(I a ϕ) + (I ϕ])^b]

ParametricPlot[{Re[func[1, 1, ϕ]]], Im[func[1, 1, ϕ]]]}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
a = 1;
b = 1;
c = 1;
d = 1;

ParametricPlot[{Re[Exp[(I phi)^a + (I phi)^b]], Im[Exp[((I phi)^c + (I phi)^d)]]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: hey, thank you it's working :)

Answer (score 2):

Your 2nd attempt is closer to something that's useful. Let's rewrite it with valid Mathematica syntax.

```
lissajous[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := 
  ParametricPlot[{Re[E^(I a t) E^(I b t)], Im[E^(I c t) E^(I d t)]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    Axes -> False]
```

Then

```
DynamicModule[{u = RandomInteger[10, 4]},
  Column[
   {Dynamic@lissajous[u],
    Button["Run", u = RandomInteger[10, 4]]}]]
```

will produce a new Lissajous figure every time you click the **Run** button. Here are some examples.

[image: liss1]

[image: liss2]

[image: liss3]